# SwiftUI App using CoreData crashes with NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

The app in question displays a set of items (Text components) on screen which you can add via a sheet that slides up from the bottom and delete them via a seperate screen (navigated from the list) which runs a seperate fetch request to show only a subset. The crash happens when I try to insert an item and is intermittent, which is why it is difficult to find where I've gone wrong.

The console output is as follows, when trying to add an item:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'*

Comment: This is a common error that occurs when your data set does not align with your view. `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are designed to update the view in response to changes in the data set. What have you done to attempt to fix this problem? Have you included the delegate methods for `NSFetchedResultsController` in your table or collection view controller?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thanks for the reply! I do not use a table or collection view controller, because SwiftUI doesn't use those. All I'm using is a ForEach in a List component to show the list.

Comment: My mistake - you do mention that you use SwiftUI. I’ve not begun to learn that new framework yet so can’t help you I’m sorry. What I can confirm without doubt is that error message is a result of you not updating your view to match an updated data set. So my recommendation is to investigate how you align views with updated data sets using SwiftUI.

Comment: @andrewbuilder No worries. Everything related to updates of UI are handled by the SwiftUI framework itself and I have no control over it other than to make it do what I want by manipulating externally, if you know what I mean. I will go with what you recommend, I will look in to and will let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @andrewbuilder I found the issue and fixed it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Tried a totally different approach to the problem since SwiftUI couldn't do on its own, had to deviate from the norms of how it's usually done. I guess this framework still needs time to become something usable. This is what I get for getting on the hype train I guess lol.

Comment: Pleased you found a solution. You might like to consider posting your own answer, if you think it might help others.

Comment: @GayalSasinda Would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @andrewbuilder Zappel I just got back after taking quite a long break, unfortunately I don't really remember what I did to resolve it now. Sorry for this, I should have added it here.

Comment: For those of you having this issue with either Core Data or another database, one thing you can check is that the order of your items in SwiftUI and how they're queried from the database are the same. If for example, you fetch records by date in Core Data, sort them by date when passing them to List or ForEach views.

I hope that helps.